# random variables related by a strictly decreasing function

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have two continuous random variables, X and Y, that are related by a strictly decreasing function:

$$Y=g(X)$$

I start with the Cumulative Density Function of Y:

$$F_{Y} = P(Y \le y)$$

Then subsituting in relation Y=g(x), I get:

$$F_{Y} = P(g(X) \le y)$$

Then, taking the inverse, I get $X=g^{-1}(y)$. But, **Why does the sign flip on the next step when taking the inverse?**

$$F_{Y} = P(X > g^{-1}(y))$$

If I remember algebra correctly, the sign only flips if multiplying the equation by a -1?  But, it doesn't look negative to me...

Comment: Look at the definition of "$g$ is a strictly decreasing function".  Then note that $g$ being strictly decreasing means $g^{-1}$ exists (with possibly a restricted domain) and is also strictly decreasing.

Comment: https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-012-introduction-to-probability-spring-2018/part-i-the-fundamentals/

Answer (score 1):

However, you can save yourself the trouble of understanding the graph if you just memorize the rule that they don't give you in the probability textbook:

Given a strictly monotonic function $y=g(x)$, with inverse function $x=h(y)=g^{-1}(y)$:

- if y=g(x) is **strictly increasing** then:

$$F_Y(Y) = P(Y \le y) = P(g(X) \le y) = P(X \le h(y)) = F_X\Big(h(y)\Big)$$

$$F_Y(Y) = F_X\Big(h(y)\Big)$$

- if y=g(x) is **strictly decreasing** then:

$$F_Y(Y) = P(Y \le y) = P(g(X) \le y) = P(X \ge h(y)) = 1 - F_X\Big(h(y)\Big)$$

$$F_Y(Y) = 1 - F_X\Big(h(y)\Big)$$

To understand why the sign flips on X relation with regards to the strictly increasing and strictly decreasing case, you need to graph y=g(x), then plot the point (y, h(y)) on the graph, and understand how the bounds $Y \le y$, can be written in terms of X, to select the same subset of y=g(x).